# Trouble printing assignment

Tags: python-3.x

I have gotten a code and after working out the indentation problem in it, it runs without errors, however now I cannot print the code into a list.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
import requests

symbol = 'AAPL'
url = "https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=" + symbol + "&type=&dateb=&owner=exclude&start=0&count=100&output=atom"
uClient = uReq(url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
html = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')
entries = html.findAll("entry")

shouldContinue = True
link = ""
for entry in entries:

    if shouldContinue and (
            entry.find("category")["term"].lower() == "10-k" or entry.find("category")["term"].lower() == "10-q" or
            entry.find("category")["term"].lower() == "20-f"):


        firstUrl = entry.find("link")["href"]

        uClientFirstUrl = uReq(firstUrl)
        page_html_firstUrl = uClientFirstUrl.read()
        uClientFirstUrl.close()
        htmlFirstUrl = soup(page_html_firstUrl, 'html.parser')

        tds = htmlFirstUrl.findAll("table")[1].findAll("td")
        foundtd = False
        for td in tds:
            if foundtd == True:
                link = "https://www.sec.gov" + td.find("a")["href"]
                foundtd = False
            if "xbrl instance" in td.text.lower():
                foundtd = True

            shouldContinue = False


def getCash(url, symbol):
    uClient = uReq(url)
    page_html = uClient.read()
    uClient.close()
    xml = soup(page_html, 'xml')

    cash = xml.findAll("us-gaap:CashAndCashEquivalentsAtCarryingValue")
    if len(cash) == 0:
        cash = xml.findAll("ifrs-full:Cash")
        if len(cash) == 0:
            cash = xml.findAll("us-gaap:CashCashEquivalentsRestrictedCashAndRestrictedCashEquivalents")
            if len(cash) == 0:
                cash = xml.findAll("us-gaap:Cash")

    return cash

    print(getCash)

getCash(url, symbol)
```

I have tried printing the assignment, as well as calling the method without any success. A sense of direction would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211470/discussion-on-question-by-dinosaurslayer-trouble-printing-assignment).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment above:

What effect do you expect from `print(getCash)`? If you want it to print the return from the `getCash()` function, delete it (it's not doing anything), and wrap your `getCash(url, symbol)` call in a `print()` function.

Basically, do this:

```
print(getCash(url, symbol))
```

Comment: Thank you. That prints ```[]```. Is it printing empty brackets because the code is not retrieving any data?

Comment: Okay I tried ending the code with print(entries) and it prints a ton of data that I will ultimately leave for a new thread

Comment: Actually nevermind. Printing entries retreieves data from the 11th line ```entries = html.findAll("entry")

Comment: @dinosaurslayer - If you accept my edit to your code, you’ll see a new line which prints a message if ‘cash’ is empty; as a debug.  If this helped, please consider upvoting and accepting the answer.  Cheers mate!

Comment: Okay, I found that function, thank you. I am just getting familiar with stack overflow (and coding/coding in python)

Comment: Thank you, but I am still getting an empty list

Comment: Yes, that’s right.  Because the data you’re searching is not in the XML.  The code is working properly in itself.  Maybe search for something else?

Comment: @dinosaurslayer - It was good working with you. Just a note that it’s proper etiquette to upvote and accept an answer if it was helpful to you.  Cheers mate and all the best!